# Multiple equal to in firebase query ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic3

below object has is_active & is_delete node so i need to query 
**select * where is_active == true && is_delete == false**
How to do that in fire base query. i know multiple order by will cause an error.
is any new way to do this.

```
{
user_id : key,
is_active : true,
is_delete : false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only filter by one value at a time in Firebase, but you can add additional client-side filtering all other parameters as long as you can fit the data into memory.

This article shows an example on client side filtering:
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/multi-property-data-filtering-with-firebase-and-angular-4/